# What is the significance of system.asynchronous_metric_log table in clickhouse server

Tags: database, clickhouse

On exploring the table sizes in clickhouse, in current deployment setup, we have more than 1.7B+ rows in table system.asynchronous_metric_log.

Is it safe to delete it?

[Documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/asynchronous_metric_log) doesn't say much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table is also quite useful, because you can use it for observability and monitoring of ClickHouse server/cluster performance. You may want to instead at least just use the system tables configuration options to configure a TTL that is appropriate for your platform (e.g. 7/30/90 days, whatever)

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables#system-tables-introduction

Comment: Wanted to make sure, on keeping ttl on these table wont in any way affect the computations of the querying we make?

Comment: Added ttl on the query_log and few other log tables, clickhouse internally renamed old table and created another table, ie. query_log_0, which contains old data I guess, when is it expected to be removed?

Comment: Yes, old log tables (based on size) get rolled over to _0, _1, etc. So removing old entries with TTLs will potentially remove those older log tables also. Using TTLs should not substantially change your computation - there is a little bit of load on the system to remove old entries, but there is also resource consumption on the system to allow to grow infinitely. Reasonable trade-off

Comment: Currently I am using clickhouse version 23.8.2.7, after doing the suggested operation, clickhouse did not remove the old tables which it created, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of it. Add this to your config somewhere (e.g. a new file in your `config.d` folder):

```
<clickhouse>
    <asynchronous_metric_log remove="1"/>
</clickhouse>
```

Comment: Got it, I think if we can control it via xml then would be better to keep ttl on the rows. Something like `<ttl>event_date + INTERVAL 10 DAY</ttl>`